# How to block part of text of an input so as not to accidentally delete it when writing

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

I have a js and php code included in my functions.php file of my child theme that makes the checkout of my woocommerce store, Selecting a country automatically displays the international country calling code. With this we achieve that customers only have to enter their phone number and do not have to enter the country's calling code.

Example: If you select Spain, +34 is automatically displayed in the telephone input

[image]

The problem I have is that this country calling code
it is not fixed, that is, as it is a field box that the client must fill in with their number, it may be that the client accidentally deletes a number from the country's calling code.

Example: Following the previous example, the client has selected the country Spain and the telephone field is automatically filled with +34. The client places himself on this box to add his phone number but inadvertently deletes the number 4 and does not realize it. Then add your phone below and formalize the order.

This results in an error with the customer's phone number in the order, because when contacting him, since number 4 is missing from the country's calling code, the customer cannot be contacted correctly.

So what I want is to be able to block that part of the country calling code that is filled in automatically so that when the customer enters his phone, he cannot accidentally delete the country code.

However, I don't know how to do it, so please help me.

This is my code:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'scripts_for_adding_country_prefix_on_billing_phone' );
function scripts_for_adding_country_prefix_on_billing_phone(){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ( function( $ ) {
            $( document.body ).on( 'updated_checkout', function(data) {
                var ajax_url = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
                country_code = $('#billing_country').val();
                var ajax_data = {
                    action: 'append_country_prefix_in_billing_phone',
                    country_code: $('#billing_country').val()
                };
                $.post( ajax_url, ajax_data, function( response ) { 
                    $('#billing_phone').val(response);
                });
            } );
        } )( jQuery );
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_append_country_prefix_in_billing_phone', 'country_prefix_in_billing_phone' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_append_country_prefix_in_billing_phone', 'country_prefix_in_billing_phone' );
function country_prefix_in_billing_phone() {
    $calling_code = '';
    $country_code = isset( $_POST['country_code'] ) ? $_POST['country_code'] : '';
    if( $country_code ){
        $calling_code = WC()->countries->get_country_calling_code( $country_code );
        $calling_code = is_array( $calling_code ) ? $calling_code[0] : $calling_code;
    }
    echo $calling_code;
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could fake this with a combination of CSS, HTML, and JS. To place a "prefix" div within the bounds of the input and avoid an overlap with `padding-left`.

The only thing left to do is to remember that when you access the value of `input` remember to prepend the country code with your JS or other logical code because it will not be included as part of the value, since we're faking it.

```js
const prefix = document.querySelector('.prefix');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const select = document.querySelector('select');

select.addEventListener('change', recalcPrefix);

function recalcPrefix(){
   prefix.innerText = select.value;
   const prefixWidth = prefix.getBoundingClientRect().width;
   input.style.paddingLeft = `${prefixWidth + 5}px`;
}

recalcPrefix();
```

```css
.input-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

 .prefix {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 13.3333px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="+34">+34</option>
  <option value="+1">+1</option>
</select>

<div class="input-wrap"> 
   <div class="prefix"></div>
   <input type="text">
</div>
```